# Regex How to identify entries with a number while ignoring other entries also with the same number

Tags: regex, string, pattern-matching

Alright, so I am still learning Regex and am having trouble understanding exactly what I need to, or can do with Regex. What I want to do is isolate entries with a number while ignoring entries also with the number where it's part of a fraction etc.
Below are examples:

(I  want to pick out these entries with an 8 in it)

I want these entries

```
Set Needle Double Spinal Plastic Hub 20G Introducer Sterile 25Gx8in
Needle L8in OD22ga Nerve Block Chiba Kit
```

(While the entries below I do not want to be picked up)

I do not want these entries, and this is where my problem comes up. every regex expression I come up with also pulls the below entries.

```
Needle Nerve Block Facet Tip 25gaX1 3/8in UniPlex Nanoline
Needle Spinal Sprotte 27ga 4 7/8in With Introducer Sterile Disposable
Needle L3 1/8in OD20ga Stim Ultraplex 360 Echo
```

For some background. I am working with large data sets of medical equipment. I have to organize these data sets and pull variables out of the entries and list these variables or values in a spreadsheet. In this case, I want to pull the value `8` inches out of the entry and then have it listed as a value of `8` inches. I need to do this while also ignoring the other entries that have values such as `7/8` or `1/8` inches. I am working with a program that does these value entries into a spreadsheet automatically, but I just have to create the rules using regex to do it. The alternative is to input each unique entry such as `25Gx8in` or `L8in` into the rules section to pull the values out. Obviously creating Regex rules to sort and pull the values out is much faster, and more preferred. Luckily the file I'm working with isn't that large with only `5,100` entries.  Thank you for any help you can provide. The people I work with aren't overly helpful in regards to this as every person I've asked simply shrugs and says, "I don't know."  I've been scouring the internet for regex information, but I just cannot seem to find what I'm looking for, though I'm sure the answer is obvious and It's something that I've just not been ablet o wrap my brain around.

Thanks in advance. I appreciate your time in reading and considering this!

Comment: Please, include any programming language if you want to work with any. It might improve the solution significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Regex that triggers these words that contain `8` but not `/8`. Demonstrated ar [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Urck8S/2):

```
(?<!\/)(\w*8\w*)
```

Explanation:

- `(\w*8\w*)` matches a word with 8 inside regardless as the first character, last or in the middle
- `(?<!\/)` is a negative look behind which doesn't allow `/` before a matched word with `8` (the point above).

To get a full line with these words, use (at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1MYOKF/1) as well):

```
^.*((?<!\/)(\w*8\w*)).*$
```

It's a simple regex that won't work for more complex structures such as `3/88in`. For this reason, I highly recommend you to discourage the limitation to Regex itself and use a programming language.

---

**Edit:**

I noticed recently these `8` numbers are always associated with an inch `in`. This might simplify all the solution to ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MM5qGS/1)):

```
.*[^\/]8in.*
```

Explanation:

- `8in` matches literally `8in`, obviously
- `[^\/]` this character must be not `/`. `[]` is a character bracket, `^` is understood as a negation inside these, and `/` must be escaped with `\`.
- `[^\/]8in` together matches `8in` which has not `/` a character on the left, so will not much ex. `3/8in`.